# How can I change the size of an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, resize, size, arraylist

I am experimenting a little bit with gamestudio.
I am now making a shooter game.
I have an array with the pointers to the enemies. When an enemy is killed, I want to remove him from the list. And I also want to be able to create new enemies.

Gamestudio uses a scripting language named lite-C. It has the same syntax as C and on the website they say, that it can be compiled with any C compiler. It is pure C, no C++ or anything else.

I am new to C. I normally program in .NET languages and some scripting languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once an array in C has been created, it is set.  You need a dynamic data structure like a Linked List or an ArrayList

Answer (score 40):

You can't.  This is normally done with dynamic memory allocation.

```
// Like "ENEMY enemies[100]", but from the heap
ENEMY* enemies = malloc(100 * sizeof(ENEMY));
if (!enemies) { error handling }

// You can index pointers just like arrays.
enemies[0] = CreateEnemy();

// Make the array bigger
ENEMY* more_enemies = realloc(enemies, 200 * sizeof(ENEMY));
if (!more_enemies) { error handling }
enemies = more_enemies;

// Clean up when you're done.
free(enemies);
```

Comment: `x = realloc(x, ...)` is a memory leak waiting to happen. (However, I realize that demonstrating how to handle dynamic allocation failures wasn't the point of this answer.)

Comment: True, and I should have checked whether `malloc` returns `NULL` as well.

Comment: Answer edited (pending peer review) to do proper error checking, because it's being used as target for dupmarking and as ~24k views already.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are static so you won't be able to change it's size.You'll need to create the linked list data structure. The list can grow and shrink on demand.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `realloc` which will allow you to resize the memory pointed to by a given pointer (which, in C, arrays are pointers).

Comment: I believe for this to work the array must be an array allocated by malloc, not on the stack. And also be warned that if it fails to allocate in-place it will free the old block and allocate a new block. This invalidates any pointers into the original block.

Comment: Ah, yea. Both of those need to be taken into account if you're going to use realloc.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. Arrays decay to pointers when passed to a function. An array and a pointer are two very different things.

Answer (score 1):

As NickTFried suggested, Linked List is one way to go.
Another one is to have a table big enough to hold the maximum number of items you'll ever have and manage that (which ones are valid or not, how many enemies currently in the list).

As far as resizing, you'd have to use a pointer instead of a table and you could reallocate, copy over and so on... definitely not something you want to do in a game.

If performance is an issue (and I am guessing it is), the table properly allocated is probably what I would use.

Comment: It's still an array implementation of a list.  You're right though, it requires knowledge of the max array size.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to lower the array size, but didn't worked like:

```
myArray = new int[10];//Or so.
```

So I've tried creating a new one, with the size based on a saved count.

```
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array1)/sizeof(array1[0]); i++){
  if (array1[i] > 0) count++;
}

int positives[count];
```

And then re-pass the elements in the first array to add them in the new one.

```
//Create the new array element reference.

int x = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array1)/sizeof(array1[0]); i++){
  if (array1[i] > 0){ positives[x] = array1[i]; x++; }
}
```

And here we have a brand new array with the exact number of elements that we want (in my case).