# Linked-List without malloc but with another approaches

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, malloc

I have an assignment asking me to use linked-list in order to store some data, but I am allowed to use only `<stdio.h>`.

I was thinking about using array, but it's not possible to extend an array in case of reaching the end of the array (which I read it's not possible from here: [How can I change the size of an array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827892/how-can-i-change-the-size-of-an-array-in-c) about 15 minutes ago).

Then I thought maybe I write `malloc` function? But it's trouble for me because I am new in C.

Another guess was thinking create new node by assigning to a variable in a function than return. I was thinking if I define a variable in a function it will allocate a new memory enough to size of memory each time when I called the function which is wrong.

Now, I don't know what to do, should I insist to be allowed using `<stdlib.h>`? Or is there a way or should I use just array with linked-list?

Comment: `malloc` is not within `stdio.h`. You can implement a linked list by having an array of `struct` and using the array index as a link, or `-1` if there is no link. If you want a dynamic affair, you can have another linked list of available elements.

Comment: Can you use a fixed size array as a memory source or do you need to handle an indeterminate size? If you can use a fixed size array you can assign the list nodes from that.

Comment: If you're a beginner, you are not expected to write your own allocator (and it would need to use a fixed-size array to allocate from, anyway). Are you sure that you're required to expand the storage when it's full?

Comment: What kind of data do you want to manage with a linked-list ?

Comment: Once an array has been defined, you cannot expand it. So you will have to define it to be large enough for your requirements. Note, I mean an array in normal variable space, not something allocated by `malloc` and friends.

Comment: Thanks for answers, since there is no information about limitation I have considered it should be expandable. I am thinking so because I know lecturer and lab asistants. I don't have problem with limited size, I can use arrays I know. Even if I use multi linked list and connect them by an array, it's not different than limited linked-list. I would use array directly instead but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: You could have a fixed size array with the elements linked into a "free" list. When you want to allocate a list element, take it from the "free" list if it is non-empty. If it is empty, print an error and exit from your program. Except that you cannot call `exit` because you are only allowed to use stdio.h, so you will have to return from your `main` function instead.

Comment: @ian-abbott, even so it is same with using linked-list with array, I mean it will be limited and I don't have problem using array linked-list. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since you cannot create your list on the heap (malloc, calloc, etc), you will have to declare your memory requirements and manage that memory internally within the list structure.

I will get you started.

```
#define LIST_MEM_POOL 1024
#define NODE_MEM_POOL 1024 

typedef struct {
    int item; /* Assuming you are storing integers in the linked list */
    struct Node *next;
} Node, *Pnode;

typedef struct {
    struct Node *head; /* Assuming singly linked list */
    int size;
} List, *Plist;

static List list_memory[LIST_MEM_POOL];
static Node node_memory[NODE_MEM_POOL];

static int used_lists = 0, free_lists = LIST_MEM_POOL;
static int used_nodes = 0, free_nodes = NODE_MEM_POOL;

Plist create_list(void) {
    Plist l = 0;
    if (used_lists < free_lists) {
        l = &list_memory[used_lists++];
        l->size = 0;
        l->head = 0;
    }
    return l;
}
```

Same idea used to create lists can be applied to creating nodes.

---

There are a few issues you need to worry about in terms of managing this memory yourself:

- How would you handle free memory?
- What happens if someone creates two lists, frees the first one, and
  tries to create a new list?
- What happens when someone tries to create a list and no memory is
  available?

Answer (score 2):

thinking out of the box ;)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N       0x20

struct data_struct
{
    char data_array[1];
    struct data_struct *next;
};

int main()
{
    FILE * fp;
    unsigned int i;
    static struct data_struct head = {0};
    static struct data_struct tmp = {0};

    fp = fopen("file.dat", "w+");

    head.data_array[0] = 'A';
    head.next = (struct data_struct *)(ftell(fp) + sizeof(struct data_struct));

    fwrite(&head, 1, sizeof(struct data_struct), fp);

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        tmp.data_array[0] = 'B' + i;
        tmp.next = (struct data_struct *)(ftell(fp) + sizeof(struct data_struct));
        fwrite(&tmp, 1, sizeof(struct data_struct), fp);
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    fread(&head, 1, sizeof(struct data_struct), fp);

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("data_array: %c\n", head.data_array[0]);

        fseek(fp, (unsigned int)head.next, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&head, 1, sizeof(struct data_struct), fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea, only `<stdio.h>`... and expandable. If you add a `setbuf()` with a fixe but large buffer size, you should increase the performance during search function.

Comment: Thanks for answer, since I had a quiz today I couldn't take care of answers enough. I haven't experienced file processes in C. I will have one more quiz and midterm by saturday, so I need to delay dealing with this assignment and I will try your suggest if I can not convince assistant to use <stdlib.h> :)